# PHP while looping a JavaScript function

Tags: php, javascript, while-loop

I'm not sure if it is possible or if there is another way to do this but I've been trying to loop a JavaScript function with PHP.

**JavaScript/PHP Function:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php
while ($songsFunction = mysql_fetch_array($result3)) {
    echo "function ".$songsFunction['songID']."(){";
    echo "document.getElementById('ogg').src='';";
    echo "document.getElementById('mp3').src='';";
    echo "document.getElementById('songName').innerHTML='';";
    echo "audio.load();";
    echo "playPause();";
    }
?>
</script>
```

I have the `songID` showing up on the playlist:

```
<?php while ($haha = mysql_fetch_array($result3)) {
    echo   '<ul>
            <li>
            <a href="#" onClick="'.$songFunction['songID'].'();">'.$songFunction['songName'].'</a>
            <a href="'.$songFunction['mp3Link'].'"><img src="../images/download.png"></a>
            </li>
            </ul>';  
    }
?>
```

The playlist correctly loops but when I get the function working, if the songID's match up, the playlist disappears.

Is this the correct way to loop a JavaScript function while pulling information through a database with variables?

Comment: I don't think generating several JavaScript functions is what you want.  Just pass in what parameters you need to a single JavaScript function.

Comment: if `$songFunction['songID']` is a number, prefix the output with a non-number - function names cannot start with number.

Comment: Sorry for the messy/unorganized code. Currently just trying to get it to work before i make everything valid/organized.

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing your JavaScript function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish but the only JavaScript I see manipulating the DOM just erases the content...

```
echo "document.getElementById('ogg').src='';";
echo "document.getElementById('mp3').src='';";
echo "document.getElementById('songName').innerHTML='';";
```

thus whatever content these items used to have would be erased.  Is this what you intended? or the source of the problem?

Comment: I know that they are erasing whats there. I don't need them to have anything in them as of now. I'm just experiencing issues with actually looping the playlist and Function correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely **NOT** the way to do it.

The scenario should be:

1. User clicks a song from playlist.
2. A click event is triggered, sending an [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) request to the php script.
3. The PHP script pulls data from DB and returns a response formatted as [json](http://www.json.org/)
4. js code uses the json response and do something with it.

Comment: just curious - why is ajax needed? a simple URL to the filename is surely all that is needed and already provided, no?

Comment: ^ Ajax really shouldn't be required for this.

Comment: The main thing you should get from this, is you should separate js and PHP code.